# yiiframework multiple optional parameters the RESTful way

Tags: yii, restful-url

I have a query interface that allows for say 4 possible fields to query, name, birthyear, astrological sign, and birthstate.  The user can provide a value for any one of these fields.  I am using AngularJS (immaterial here) and YiiFramework (material).

I have seen answers to questions similar to this, but for the most part, people end up using querystring parameters.  I can account for that in my urlManager, but would prefer to do this in the 'right' RESTful way.  I have seen examples showing how to do this as:

/myservice/index.php/names/jones?birthyears=&signs=leo&birthstates=maine - meaning they did not supply birthyear

My thought to do this completely with paths skipping blank values.  Is this a reasonable approach:

/myservice/index.php/api/modelname/names/jones/birthyears//signs/leo/birthstates/maine

if so, then i am struggling with the urlManager pattern

array('api/find', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/names/<names:(|\w+)>/birthyears/<birthyears:(|\d{4})>/signs/<signs:(|\w+)>/birthstates/<birthstates:(|\w+)>', 'verb'=>'GET')

when i pass the above path to this i do not get the expected resolution.  I am sure there is a better way to deal with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it here and it worked.

How are you setting the parameters of your urlManager?

The urlFormat property is set to 'path'?

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path', // You have to leave it like that.
 //   'urlSuffix' => '.html',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'caseSensitive' => true,
    'useStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => array(
       array('api/find', 'pattern'=>'<model:\w+>/names/<names:(|\w+)>/birthyears/<birthyears:(|\d{4})>/signs/<signs:(|\w+)>/birthstates/<birthstates:(|\w+)>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
       // Other rules here
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you, i am trying this again now with your additional urlManager parameters in there.  I had it set to urlFormat path, but not the other parameters.  I am getting an error resolving the controller:  "The system is unable to find the requested action"

Comment: I ended up removing the separators and was able to get the system working.  I gather this is not restful, but my path is now something like:  /jones//leo/maine - which is matched by /<names:(|\w+)>/<birthyears:(|\d{4})>/<signs:(|\w+)>/<birthstates:(|\w+)> and now putting back the groupings and that works too.  so, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to have helped, needing just talk!